# XML unescaping with Zipper in Scala

Tags: xml, scala, scalaz, zipper

Suppose I need to *unescape* XML escaped characters in a given string: e.g. I need to replace `&amp;` with `&`, `&quot;` with `"`, `&lt;` with `<` etc. I would prefer a purely functional solution.

Does it make sense to do it with `scalaz.Zipper` ? `Zipper` allows checking the characters to the right of the focus and skipping them while moving forward. Won't it be an overkill ? Would you suggest a simpler solution ?

Answer (score 1):

`Zipper` is better at dealing with 1:1 character-character mapping that needs access to the characters on either side, not a mapping that changes the number of characters in the string.

I'd recommend either using an XML parsing library (scala has a reasonable built-in-ish one in the form of scala-xml), a string escaping/unescaping utility function (there's one in apache commons that handles xml entities IIRC) or if you really want a fancy solution then maybe parsing your string with scala-parser-combinators.

Comment: Thanks. I probably should write the `unescape` function and see how  it goes. I still thinks that such a function might be a good case for `Zipper`.

Comment: Yes, I can use unescape from Apache. I've looked at the code. It took dozens lines of code to implement this function.